# Accept any JSON data into .NET Core Web API controller (No Model)

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want an angular application to send any JSON data to a .Net Core WebAPI controller.

I don't want to have a pre-defined model accepting the JSON in the controller function.

I don't know how to accept it. Kindly help. In Angular, the data is `JSON.stringified` and POSTED

Here is my angular TS code that sends the JSON:

[image: Here is my angular TS code that sends the JSON (this.data, fetched from angular JSON Editor)]

Controller that can accept any form of JSON:

[image: Controller that can accept any form of JSON ?]

Comment: If you stringified your data in Angular which means your backend must take a string from body. so you can write `[FromBody] string body` . Otherwise you need to use `StreamReader`but I am not sure is it ethic or not. May be you can write different methods for them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the client is posting JSON, you can define a `string` parameter that will accept any format JSON data.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadJson([FromBody] string json)
{
    return Ok();
}
```